# counting consecutive value in a column by id

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id= c(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  name= c("john","bob","bob","bob","bob","bob","leo","bob","bob","max","mike","mike","mike","mike","mike","mike","mike","Ronaldo","mike")
)
```

I want to count how many times a particular value is present in name column back to back group by id

what I expect is as below:

```
expected_output<-data.frame(
id=c(2,3),
column_name="name",
value=c("bob","Mike"),
count=c(5,7))
```

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: Why `id = 1` is not there in final output?

Comment: @RonakShah because ill will count only those which have consecutive values id=1 is having only one value no need to count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the maximum consecutive `name` for each `id` you can first `count` consecutive names using `data.table::rleid` and keep only the max value in each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(id, name, cons = data.table::rleid(name), name = 'count') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(which.max(count)) %>%
  select(-cons)

#     id name  count
#  <dbl> <chr> <int>
#1     1 john      1
#2     2 bob       5
#3     3 mike      7
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is somehow what I want ill work on rest by my own.
:) <3

Comment: you can add `filter(count > 1)` to remove id = 1.

Comment: could you please reply to my email? I send you an email

Comment: I am resending it now